# Unwrapping Json Swift (found nil)

Tags: json, string, swift, nsdictionary

i currently trying to decode Json in Xcode, but i not succed to get one of them.

This is what i get :

```
[
  {
     "id": "1",
     "title": "bmw",
     "price": "500.00",
     "description": "330",
     "addedDate": "2015-05-18 00:00:00",
     "user_id": "1",
     "user_name": "CANOVAS",
     "user_zipCode": "32767",
     "category_id": "1",
     "category_label": "VEHICULES",
     "subcategory_id": "2",
     "subcategory_label": "Motos",
     "bdd": {} 
  }
     "pictures": 
        [
         { "name": "http://cars.axlegeeks.com/sites/default/files/4315/media/images/2014_BMW_Z4_sDrive28i_3790993.jpg"
         }
        ]
  }
]
```

And i want to get the value of "name" for the "Pictures" lines but i have the error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping value".

For the others values i proceed this way :

```
let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as! NSDictionary

            //Browse into JSON to get datas
            let resp = jsonData["0"] as! NSDictionary
                let user_nameR = resp["user_name"] as! String
                let user_zipCodeR = resp["user_zipCode"] as! String
                let titleR = resp["title"] as! String
                let priceR = resp["price"] as! String
                let descriptionR = resp["description"] as! String
```

Thank's for your help !

Comment: What do you see if you `println(urlData!)`?

Comment: I already put this control into my code, i get  :  urlData: 2063404224
<7b223022 3a7b2269 64223a22 31222c22 7469746c 65223a22 626d7722 2c227072 ......>

Comment: that's actually helpful.  Could you update your question with the full value of urlData.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pictures is in not in the subdictionary your other values are. This should work, but you should check all values if they are nil before you force cast them.

```
if let pictureArray = jsonData["pictures"] as? NSArray
{
    if let pictureDict = pictureArray.firstObject as? NSDictionary
    {
        if let pictureName = pictureDict.objectForKey("name") as? String
        {
            NSLog("Picture name: %@", pictureName)
        }
    }
}
```

jsonData contains two sub-dictionaries, one without a key and one with key 'pictures'. Pictures is an array containing one sub-dictionary.

Comment: thanks you for your help !                                                                              I tried this :     if resp["pictures"]as? NSArray != nil {
                         let pictures = resp["name"] as! String
                    
                         NSLog("%@", pictures);
                    
                }
But i don't know if it's the good way to do it, by the way my app ignore the code when i launch it, it make me think it's not good

Comment: The exact error is : "Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject?' with an index of type 'Int'"

Comment: It work, and furthermore, you make me undersand where my mistake was. Thanks you again !

Comment: You are welcome. But don't forget to check if the other values are really present and not nil by using optional binding like in my example code. If you don't do this and one of the data elements is nil and you use it, you're app will crash.